# Add newlines to body of mailto: link

Tags: html, mailto

My input is from a textbox from HTML form. Using `mailto:` link, it will send to someone's email. The format on the body of the message is like this:

```
First=testing&Last=testing&txtChar=123456&emailcheck=testing%40gmail.com
```

But I want my output like this:

```
First=testing
Last=testing
txtChar=123456
emailcheck=testing%40gmail.com
```

Comment: You might want to specify what language you're working with, and what you've tried so far to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start a new line use, %0A and spaces are %20

```
First=testing%0ALast=testing%0A&txtChar=123456%0Aemailcheck=testing%40gmail.com
```

To convert it to normal text you have to add `enctype="text/plain"`to your form;

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:reyjavebobbyr@gmail.com?Subject=Interactive Test" name="validation" onSubmit="return checkbae()" enctype="text/plain>
```

Comment: sir this is my code : <form method="post" action="mailto:reyjavebobbyr@gmail.com?Subject=Interactive Test" name="validation" onSubmit="return checkbae()">

Comment: enctype="text/plain"              thanks sir! :D :)

Comment: sorry sir i forget. because it is my first time to ask question. thanks again sir

Comment: @JaveBobbyRey No problem :) Anymore questions feel free to post a new question and link it here and I will have a look

Comment: ok sir! see you next time. Cheers !